# Is it common for professors to ask a postdoc to start working without compensation while waiting for paperwork to be completed?

Tags: ethics, postdocs, international

I was wondering if it is common for professors to ask a new international postdoc to work without compensation while waiting for paperwork to be completed.

I was in an interview and the professor hinted at something along this line, when I brought up the topic of the lengthy visa process to be expected.

A few notes:

- The professor is not my PhD advisor. He's at a different university in a different country. So, my question is not similar to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148938/is-it-unethical-to-expect-ones-phd-students-to-work-after-graduation-without-co) one.
- The whole visa process could take 3 months.
- The work contract may include a start date that is earlier than the visa issuing date (in this case ≈ 3 months earlier) but the university cannot pay me for that period without a valid document/visa. That's why I mentioned 'without compensation'. Correct me if you think I am misunderstanding this aspect.
- I understand that the scope of the postdoc's work is related to a project that has tight deadlines, which is why the professor wants work done as soon as possible. But, I find that the duration in which this situation would last is long. A maximum of 1 month may seem tolerable but not longer.

Is this common in academia for international hires? And would it be ethical?

Comment: In some jurisdictions, working without the appropriate type of visa may be illegal irrespective of whether or not you're being paid.  I suggest seeking legal advice before trying it.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Not sure I got your point. How do you prove that you did work before getting a contract? What kind of document would you show them?

Comment: @JFabianMeier Please don't give such dangerous advice. Working without a visa does not end well if discovered. It might be good for you if you are a German citizen (and even then, you can get into trouble because it might be *Schwarzarbeit*).

Comment: @Roland Sorry, this was just a comment, not meant to be advice (please don't try this!).

Comment: Where would you be during that period? Still at home (or wherever you have valid status to stay and work), or already in the target country? The latter may get you in quite a bit of trouble. Is the compensation adjustable? I.e. if the total engagement is 12 months, can they pay you the equivalent of 12 months over a 9 months period (i.e. at 133% the normal rate), or is the monthly amount fixed (and thus you would be losing 3 months of compensation)?

Comment: @jcaron Still at home (or wherever you have valid status to stay and work) . Regarding the second question, I'm not sure. I'd have to be at a more advanced stage of the hiring process to know (and ask about) that.

Comment: When I read only the subject line, I though maybe the payments would be made retroactively after the paperwork was complete. In that case I think there might be no problem other than that of proving without the paperwork that promises had been made. But if it's illegal for them to start paying you until you have your visa, maybe you should tell the professor about the legalities, which might not apply to other postdocs because they didn't come from another country.

Comment: Can you negotiate that the contract says they also either increase your salary prorated, or pay you a lumpsum? as @jcaron says. Otherwise your question as stated *"Is it common...?"* is kinda offtopic, and strongly depends on which country and visa laws. Working before you get legal work authorization is generally a very very bad idea.

Comment: common?: I'm sure it is. Appropriate or legal?: of course not!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Asking someone to work without compensation is illegal in many jurisdictions. It is also hardly ethical. Unfortunately, it is also not uncommon in academia.

In modern "publish or perish" academia professors are often under a huge deal of pressure from university administration to produce countless high-quality papers and teach ever-growing number of courses. A significant proportion of academics feel that they are forced to work extra hours to meet the expectations of their universities. This draining and insecure work environment often impacts the judgement of academics when they manage the work of their PhD students and postdocs.  Many  sincerely believe that they should "prepare" their students/postdocs to the hard realities of academia and make them more competitive by demanding to produce results at a cost of personal life and well-being. This is wrong, but unfortunately, wrong things do happen in this world and in academia as well.

UPD: Answering some questions in comments, I feel that I have to explain why the PI's behaviour is wrong. I don't think it is a subjective judgement.

1. Forcing someone to work without compensation and without contract is modern slavery. Slavery is wrong. Postdoc are employees, they have terminal education degrees, they are professionals and they do important research work, not some glorified "training". Forcing a postdoc to work without contract and compensation is wrong.
2. But perhaps, the PI was not forcing the postdoc, but merely asked them nicely whether they would like to volunteer? Well, let's see. Postdoc does not know whether they can say "no" to their PI without risking their contract or compromising the work relations with their PI during their contract. There are so many ways in which postdoc's whole career depends on their PI's opinion (access to research resources, appraisals, extensions of contract, letters of recommendation, etc).  In this situation postdocs are under a huge pressure to say "yes" to unfair and illegal proposals. That's why even proposing to work without contract is abusive, morally wrong and often illegal.

Comment: I think the spin in the second paragraph is unnecessarily negative. One's personal life and well-being does not necessarily hinge on a (forced) multi-month break between PhD and post-doc. Conversely, there is the potential for a "win-win" situation, in which the post-doc benefits by having better chances on a competitive job market. Whether one associates that with pressure and a hard reality is subjective. Some people blossom in competition.

Comment: Working without compensation is common for start-ups, where you in tern are given equity which, if the company is a success, will be worth more than your salary would have been (although tell that to the bank when they ask you to pay bills.) And you could definitely make the case that the project here is much the same - a start-up that is hoping to get funding in the near future. The equity here, clearly, is the ability publish the paper which you would expect to boost your career.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Requesting someone to work without compensation is wrong; I don't see anything subjective here. The situation in which highly educated people (such as professors) resort to such wrong and likely illegal practices is also wrong. It is true that competition is good for some people, but it does not make it right for everyone. There are clear legal and ethical boundaries here, and unfortunately people in modern academia do not always see or respect them, particularly under pressure.

Comment: In my opinion (which apparently is not everyone's), postdocs are not trainees. Still they are in a career stage where the goal is to build a strong profile, hence it's indeed advisable to use the time productively - especially since papers take time to get published. The reference to slavery doesn't seem appropriate (slaves are forced and not asked). I do agree that power dynamics might might play a role that could be problematic. The degree of this will depend on the exact communication - for example, the PI might proactively say that a "no" is absolutely OK, which would remove pressure.

Comment: @corsiKa That is an incredibly toxic attitude. Papers are not money, you cannot be compensated in papers.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim No, of course you can't. As I said, you can't pay bills in equity. But if you believe the funding will come through, I see no problem with investing your time in the project with the understanding you will be compensated when the funding does come in. I am NOT suggesting you simply work for free in order to get your name on the paper. Not at all. Merely that if you can afford to do so financially, and have confidence the funding will come through, it doesn't seem to be a problem continuing the project until said funding does come in.

Comment: @corsiKa No, still toxic. You DID say to work for free to get your name on the paper. Working on a project until your visa comes in is not at all similar to what you propose

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim No, I absolutely did not. It's not my fault you decided what I said without reading it properly. And it really is exactly the same. You work without pay until the funding arrives, at which point you're compensated for the work you did. Again, if you have confidence everything will go well, and you can afford to, why hold up a project you believe in? Being inspired isn't toxic.

Comment: @corsiKa You have contradicted yourself so many times I'm not going to spend my time pointing out where you said the things you said you did not. You are misunderstanding the situation entirely. The OP *will* get paid when their visa comes through. Working now will not change that. Because it is illegal to work without their visa, they cannot be compensated retroactively if they work now. *Again, if you have confidence everything will go well, and you can afford to, why hold up a project you believe in?* Because you aren't being paid?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I did miss the part that says the university is unwilling to retroactively pay for the work done. I had read it as they simply can't issue a check until the paperwork comes in. Obviously that changes the calculus.

Comment: @corsiKa Freelancers are paid once when their project is completed. In contrast, academic staff are compensated for time spent on a particular project or task, or generally in employment. A person without visa can not legally work, hence can not normally be compensated. In extraordinary circumstances HRs and Finance may find a way of paying retrospectively, e.g. for famous professors or high-level admin like vice-chancellors and their teams. But for a poor postdoc? Never.

Answer (score 10):

There is a difference between no compensation and delayed compensation. An important question is how routine this paperwork is. If it is merely a bureaucratic hold up and you are already in town, why not get a jump start on your research? It could make the research when you officially start easier, and could lead to a better overall research experience, which could help your long-term career.

Hopefully the professor is enthusiastic about the research. From their point of view, this could be *allowing* you to start early rather than *forcing* you to do so. The only thing that would be a red-flag for me would be if you weren't given any choice. You should have the freedom to say something like "I would prefer to get settled while I'm waiting for the paperback. Can you suggest some background material that I might read in the meantime?" (or words to that effect, the business about reading at the end since you would still want to communicate a bit of enthusiasm for the project).

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph, that's an important aspect. About the first paragraph I'm unsure. Unless the PI suggests that the postdoc can leave the job early and will still get paid, there will be a discrepancy between "time worked" and "time paid for", so indeed, some time without compensation.

Comment: "You should have the freedom to say something like "I would prefer to get settled while I'm waiting for the paperback. Can you suggest some background material that I might read in the meantime?"  " Exactly, this sounds like something I would say indeed (maybe 1 month before the official start of the position and after an official offer has been made). However, I was surprised to see the professor say I could start working (on publications directly) and not even background material. As others have suggested above, this may be beneficial. But, I would've preferred to take the initiative myself.

Answer (score 7):

The underlying issue you're encountering here is that, generally speaking, a postdoc position is considered an education (albeit a paid one) for the position holder. As a consequence, telling a postdoc before they formally start their job that they might want to start reading some background material or working on the project (presumably while they have no other job because (i) they've graduated with their PhD and (ii) are waiting for their visa to process) is not so different from telling a student at the beginning of the summer break "Look, this is the material I'm going to cover in MATH 517, and here is the book we're going to use; why don't you start reading up on that material now already instead of waiting for the beginning of the fall semester?".

Strictly speaking, it might of course be illegal to have someone work *for you* while they are not paid. But graduate students are also not paid and still work on research projects -- the point simply being that it actually benefits both the graduate student and the future postdoc to already work on the project because *they are also working for themselves* (through publications or, more generally, for future job prospects).

Comment: I'm not sure about the extent to which a postdoc is always regarded as an education, but I'd certainly subscribe to the view that postdocs (and researchers in general) are to a significant extent working "for themselves" (i.e. in their own interests), and that that's what makes any unpaid work they might decide to do make sense. Note that: (i) it's quite common for research projects to persist across jobs, rather than being tied to them, (ii) it's quite common to evaluate researchers on their individual productivity, and (iii) your name's on your work.

Comment: Given those considerations, only doing research when you're being paid for it seems self-defeating, because it's a reasonable bet that (i) you might want another research job in the future, and (ii) when you do, you're going to be evaluated based on your productivity, including during the times when you didn't have a job, and against people who were working that whole time.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz , thanks, I haven't thought about it that way. I was mostly focusing on the length of the duration.

Comment: "generally speaking, a postdoc position is considered an education (albeit a paid one) for the position holder". This is simply not true. In most European countries a post-doc is a paid job with a FTE contract, and asking a post-doc to do free work is illegal. By those standards, every job is "education" in that the person gains experience, and thus people are "working for themselves for future job prospects".

Comment: @JorgeLeitao It isn't completely wrong to claim that in academia, in some sense *every* position you might ever hold is considered an education and that an application you send in for any job you apply isn't just evaluated by your "experience in a field" (as would often be the case in industry) but your cumulative output over years or decades. As such, unpaid work can often pay off later on. That's what makes people work on weekends and, at least in the US, during the summer when many of us are not actually paid (professors typically have 9-month contracts every year).

Comment: All of that, of course, is separate from the question whether that is a humane system. Also, whether that is legal. But these are separate questions, and the original question was just about whether it is common. It *is* common, though we can certainly agree that it's maybe neither legal nor moral.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I understand that sentiment, and I am sorry that you have to do unpaid work. However, that sentiment is not "general"; it is common in the US and other countries, but it is uncommon in Europe. As it stands, this answer incentivizes people to work pro-bono 'because that's the way it is'. Also, comparing a post-doc with a graduate student is funny for EU standards.

Answer (score 4):

This might depend on the country you want to work in.

> The work contract may include a start date that is earlier than the
> visa issuing date.

I doubt that you get such a work contract. A competent administration won't sign it.

I'm in Germany and I just hired an international PhD student (here they often are employees in the same way as post-docs). The process was as follows:

1. They applied for a 90 day (work) visa at the embassy in their home country. For this our administration provided the necessary documents (most importantly confirming the job offer). It took about a month until the visa was issued.
2. Once that visa had been issued, they got a signed contract for the time period covered by the visa. They came to Germany and started working.

The following step is what was supposed to happen. Unfortunately, in reality it became slightly more exciting because they came to Germany just when we went into the COVID lock-down. But everyone involved (our administration, the visa office) was very helpful and we successful sorted everything out.

3. Once in Germany, you go to the immigration office and apply for a long-term work visa (once again, with documents from our administration). As soon as that is issued, the contract for the full time period is signed.

**Don't work without having a work visa.** If the authorities discover that somehow, you will be deported and will never get a visa again. In most cases it's not worth the risk. However, there are some special visa options for scientists (see [there](https://www.research-in-germany.org/en/plan-your-stay/entry-and-residence.html) for some options in Germany). But in any case, you need to have a visa (and not a tourist visa) if you are not a EU citizen.

However, nothing prevents you from preparing by studying literature, attending online meetings, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that a collaboration between two researchers (one of which will eventually hire the other as post-doc) would necessarily be considered as work in the sense of visa regulations? I'm not saying you're wrong, but to me, that seems a tricky legal question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that after they are "eventually hire[d]", the period preceding that will be considered work. Immigration authorities take a dim view of such shady practices. But since you would need a visa anyway, why not do it the proper way? It shouldn't even take more time.

Comment: I think it's very unclear if this practice is indeed shady (see e.g., WolfgangBangerth's answer for a contrasting view), hence my question. Your answer could be strengthened by including evidence for your claim.

Comment: A post-doc is not considered a student in any way or form in Germany. *Legally* speaking, there is no such position as post-doc in Germany. As I write, this might be different in other countries.

Comment: Regardless of how the position will be called (probably "Wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter"), a central point of a postdoc is to further the person's career prospects, unlike most forms of work (which are an exchange between workforce and money). I still think the legal assessment is not obvious and would benefit from actual evidence.

Comment: Added something.

Comment: Thanks @Roland for outlining the different steps of the process! This clears things up and confirms that I was misunderstanding the process related to the work contract.

Comment: However, my concern comes from the following situation:
If, on day n, you start looking for visa appointments, the earliest date you will find will be between n+2 months and n+2.5 months. (This is confirmed by a family member who went through this process, for a study visa appointment though, but I think the pool of slots is the same, whether it's work or studies) If we also add the 1 month processing time you mention, the whole process could take up to 3.5 months. What I'd like to know is if it's normal to expect one's postdoc to start taking on his/her job responsibilities during this time.

Comment: @acad-user You should specify both countries (your home country and the country you plan to work in). In Germany, there might be some grey area if you are already in the country with a student visa. Otherwise, it's simply impossible as you can't enter the country without a visa and using a tourist visa would block you from getting any other visa. Now, it is probably common that you are expected to prepare during this period by studying literature or attending some online meetings ...

Comment: @acad-user Btw, my PhD student is from India: He managed to get a visa within 5 weeks after receiving the job offer. However, that certainly depends on the resources of the respective embassy.

Comment: @Roland yes, I was referring to Germany in my last comment. I'm a third country citizen (not on a student visa in Germany, actually not even in Germany yet)

Answer (score 2):

You should encourage them to write a work contract that begins at a time when they will be allowed to pay you, and not before, unless they are agreeing to give back pay (I would be hesitant even in this case). You don't want any legal trouble for working when you are not legally allowed to work, this can be just as big a deal as hiring someone when you are not legally allowed to hire them.

As for whether this is common, it probably varies by country. In Germany, I'm sure this almost never happens; but very few countries are as structured in following rules as Germany. In other countries (not naming names) you might find that sketchy things can happen, like once you get there they write a new work contract that doesn't actually begin until your visa does, and you are left "working" the first 3 months without pay OR a contract (or so I hear, hahahahahaha :/ ). Or even if you refuse to work, you are already in the new country as a "visitor" with no income.

Comment: I worked at a German university as a bachelor student tutoring a small class. The job contract was delayed because the university messed something up, so it started one month later, two weeks later then the course was supposed to start. I was explicitly told by HR not to teach the course for the first two weeks and only start when the contract begins. Despite that they increased my pay for the next months in order to fully compensate for my financial loss in the first month.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum So who taught the course, then?

Comment: @user151413 first week didn't happen anyways (for all students, also in the other groups) and the second week was just some organization stuff so I just sent an email instead.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum Ah, so you *did* work those weeks, just there was nothing to do! (Or was it the physical presence which was not ok, not the teaching as such?)

Comment: @user151413 it was not that big of a deal, they just told me I should only start teaching when my contract starts. No one would have noticed, didn't even bother the professor with it.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum: I think they wanted to prevent a permant work contract to form. The university *letting* you work (knowingly without protesting) constitutes a valid work contract (conduct implying intent). *Fixed term* clauses in work contracts, however, are valid only in written form. So the unwritten work contract would have been a permanent one and there are few things scarier to university administration than a work contract accidentally becoming permanent. By telling you not to work before the contract starts, they prevented such a permanent contract. The only one who they were...

Comment: afraid of noticing is you. @MorganRodgers: yes, very German since it was a legal problem about labor law which is always very country specific.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Well, let's put it like this: I'm still curious how a certain German university who hired me on a 2 month contract last Dec+Jan but took until almost *May* to figure out how much to pay me and actually do that will handle the annual wage tax declarations (correct the 2019 one with a payment that happened *far* outside the actuarial grace period at the beginning of the year or declare my work in 2020 but by law *should* have happened in the old year). German university administration is often very much to the letter of the law (with the notable exception of paying in time - both

Comment: employees for their first wages and contractors). But if you happen to deal with the combination of such an administration and a professor who has not a "legal mindset" that considers deadlines, notification periods etc. then expect that a certain amount of mess to happen. What German administration is very bad at is dealing with/recovering from things that did not happen as supposed. (I say this having the comparison/contrast also of dealing with an Italian university and a professor who was versed in their administrative processes)